# Function will not display random image if more than 5 listed in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've worked tirelessly on this problem the last few days.  I'm just a math teacher, and I don't have a ton of coding experience ... but this code will work until I place more than 5 images in the array.  I would like to created a code that randomly displays one image out of a set of as many as I want, and has a specific url tagged to it.

```
<div id="box">
    <a id="a"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"example1", Href:"example1" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"example2", Href:"example2" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"example3", Href:"example3" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"example4", Href:"example4" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"example5", Href:"example5" }
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
</script>
```

So the above code will work, until I add a 6th image.  Please help! (And please don't make fun of me if it's a simple fix -- remember, I'm a public servant!)

Comment: what happens when you add the 6th image ?

Comment: Could you show exactly what are the values of `ImgSrc` and `Href` of this 6th image ? Are you sure that this 6th image is present in appropriate server directory (like `example5` and `example4` etc... files) ?

Comment: can you add the code that's causing the issue

Comment: Code seems fine, check for other issues such as mentioned by @myhau. One suggestion: replace the [imageUrlPair = {...}, imageUrlPair = {...}, ...] with just [{...}, {...}, ...] as the former declares and re-assigns a new global variable which after evaluation of your array literal just points to the last array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to separate your elements with a comma `,` when you added the sixth?

---

### FAILING EXAMPLE:

```html
<div id="box">
    <a id="a"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    { ImgSrc:"example1", Href:"example1" },
    { ImgSrc:"example2", Href:"example2" },
    { ImgSrc:"example3", Href:"example3" },
    { ImgSrc:"example4", Href:"example4" },
    { ImgSrc:"example5", Href:"example5" } // note the missing comma here
    { ImgSrc:"example6", Href:"example6" }
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
</script>
```

---

### WORKING EXAMPLE:

```html
<div id="box">
    <a id="a"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    { ImgSrc:"example1", Href:"example1" },
    { ImgSrc:"example2", Href:"example2" },
    { ImgSrc:"example3", Href:"example3" },
    { ImgSrc:"example4", Href:"example4" },
    { ImgSrc:"example5", Href:"example5" }, // works with comma added
    { ImgSrc:"example6", Href:"example6" }
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  That was it.  I left the comma out when I was copying and pasting.  I knew it was something simple and I was just completely blind to it.

Comment: Sure thing, but I'm new to this forum.  How do you do that?

Comment: Haha, gotcha.  I clicked the up arrow but not the checkmark.  Thanks again!  Enjoy the rest of the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the inner assignment of

```
imageUrlPair = { /* ... */ }
//^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in the array, because you need only the object and no assignment.

```js
var images = [{ ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/1/", Href: "example1" }, { ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/2/", Href: "example2" }, { ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/3/", Href: "example3" }, { ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/4/", Href: "example4" }, { ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/5/", Href: "example5" }, { ImgSrc: "http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/6/", Href: "example6" }]

function randImg() {
    var size = images.length,
        x = Math.floor(size * Math.random()),
        randomItem = images[x];

    document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
    document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
```

```html
<div id="box"><a id="a"><img id="image" /></a></div>
```